# How to read large txt file (80MB) from s3 bucket in aws lambda node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am going to read large txt file which is bigger than 80MB from s3 in aws lambda function.
In the txt file, I have to extract some urls.
But I can't read the file since it's too large.
Here is my code.

```js
console.log("Loading function");

import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const s3 = new S3Client({ region: "us-west-2" });

function getObject(Bucket, Key) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key });

    try {
      const response = await s3.send(getObjectCommand);

      // Store all of data chunks returned from the response data stream
      // into an array then use Array#join() to use the returned contents as a String
      let responseDataChunks = [];

      // Handle an error while streaming the response body
      response.Body.once("error", (err) => reject(err));

      // Attach a 'data' listener to add the chunks of data to our array
      // Each chunk is a Buffer instance
      response.Body.on("data", (chunk) => responseDataChunks.push(chunk));

      // Once the stream has no more data, join the chunks into a string and return the string
      response.Body.once("end", () => resolve(responseDataChunks.join("")));
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle the error or throw
      return reject(err);
    }
  });
}

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log("Received event:");

  // Get the object from the event and show its content type
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(
    event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")
  );
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };
  try {
    // const respnse = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
    const data = await getObject(bucket, key);
    //   let objectData = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); // Use the encoding necessary
    return "";
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
    console.log(message);
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work because the file is too large.

Is there anyone who has a solution?

Comment: What is the error that is logged? And what is the configured memory size of your lamba function?

Comment: Why do you think the file is too large?

Comment: Memory size is 128MB

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by increasing memory to 512MB and runtime limit to 3min.